# Cannot populate data from Command

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a simple example where I want to populate my Listbox values from enter command which is bounded to Textbox

My **MainWindow.xaml**

```
 <Window.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <TextBox  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="54,32,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120">
        <TextBox.InputBindings>
            <KeyBinding Command="{Binding Path=EnterCommand}" Key="Enter"/>
        </TextBox.InputBindings>
    </TextBox>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyList}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="107" Margin="54,70,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>

</Grid>
```

**VieModel**

```
public class ViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private List<string> _list;
    public IRelayCommand EnterCommand { get; protected set; }
    public ViewModel()
    {
        CreateEnterCommand();

    }

    private void CreateEnterCommand()
    {
        this.EnterCommand = new RelayCommand(EnterCommandExecuted, CanExecuteEnterCommand);
    }

    private void EnterCommandExecuted(object obj)
    {
        FillData();//Pass your Data here
    }

    private bool CanExecuteEnterCommand(object obj)
    {

        return true;
    }

    private void FillData()
    {
        MyList = new List<string>();
        MyList.Add("1");
        MyList.Add("2");
        MyList.Add("3");
        MyList.Add("4");
    }

    public List<string> MyList
    {
        get
        {
            return _list;
        }
        set
        {
            _list = value;

        }

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

The listbox is not populated it only populates when  `FillData` is in the constructor. Also how can I check if the textbox is empty or not before firing ??

Comment: Invoking propertyChanged in your MyList setter ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it doesn't update is because noone is telling the view that new data is available.

If you are using an [`ObservableCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) instead for your MyList property, which implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`, the view will update when you add items.

The only thing you need to change is the way you create your MyList property, change it to

```
MyList = new ObservableCollection<string>();
```

and have the property return an IList (or an ObservableCollection) instead and you should be fine.

Also, when using collections like this, you should create your MyList in the constructor, and make the collection readonly. This is so you don't accidently assign your list to a new instance, and loose any events you may have attached. For instance, if your property is public, another class may set the list to something else, but because you don't fire a property change event, the view will still be bound to the old list, so any items you add to the list will not work.

```
private readonly ObservableCollection<string> _list;
public ViewModel()
{
    _list = new ObservableCollection<string>();
}

public ObservableCollection<string> MyList
{
    get { return _list; }
}

public void FillData()
{
    // add any items you like to either _list or MyList,
    // because it's an observable collection, there's no
    // need to recreate the list, the view will be notified either way
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason it isn't working is that your `MyList` property setter isn't raising the `PropertyChanged` event.

In your particular case, you could make `MyList` an `ObservableCollection<string>` instead of `List<string>`, assign the property once in the constructor, then just clear the list and add items to it from the `FillData` method. This also means you no longer need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public IRelayCommand EnterCommand { get; protected set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        this.EnterCommand = new RelayCommand(EnterCommandExecuted, CanExecuteEnterCommand);
        this.MyList = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    }

    private void EnterCommandExecuted(object obj)
    {
        FillData();//Pass your Data here
    }

    private bool CanExecuteEnterCommand(object obj)
    {
        return true;
    }

    private void FillData()
    {
        MyList.Clear();
        MyList.Add("1");
        MyList.Add("2");
        MyList.Add("3");
        MyList.Add("4");
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> MyList { get; private set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to make couple of changes in your view model. Please change type of your MyList to ObservableCollection. You can also fire NotifyCHange event from your set, but that will only fire if you change whole MyList Instance.

```
public ObservableCollection<string> MyList
    {
        get
        {
            return _list;
        }
        set
        {
            _list = value;

        }

    }
```